# SAP BPCS include errors

Tags: sap-erp, sap-bw

Is there anyway to include error or warnings handling in Sap?

I use SAP BPCS script and I would like to include error and warnings handling in it, taking all records from Excel file.

A way to include error or warnings handling in Sap?

Comment: The question is as unclear as asking a way to include error or warnings handling in Microsoft. All depends which programming language or software you are talking about. I'm aware of SAP BPC software, but I don't know what can be "BPCS script". A SAP programming language? Please add context, code, and so on. For more information, visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.